# Multiple async calls in the same statement in C#

Tags: c#

Are all calls happening even if the first returns false?
Is the second one waiting for the first one?

`if (await callAsync() && await callAsync()) {...}`

`if (await callAsync() & await callAsync()) {...}`

`if (await callAsync() || await callAsync()) {...}`

Comment: If the first condition returns false then rest all conditions arent checked. [Short-circuting](https://kodify.net/csharp/if-else/short-circuit-if/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In both cases, the calls still happen *sequentially in the execution flow*, not in parallel. In the first case the second call only happens if the first returns `true`; in the second case, both will happen either way (assuming no exceptions are thrown).